# Change the Display date format without using CONVERT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**dbcc useroptions**
 shows the date format

later i changed format using
**set dateformat dmy**

even though i changed the format the date is being display in the the format of yyyymmdd

how to change the display format without using *CONVERT*

Comment: You don't. SQL Server just returns a `date` or `datetime`. It's then up to the client software that receives that value to decide how it's going to *format* that data for display purposes. The way that SSMS formats dates isn't configurable, and even if it was, why would you? It's just an ad-hoc querying tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you didn't mentioned that we can't use ***CAST***, Would the following work for you?

> select CAST(getdate() as nvarchar(30))

I know i am not being too fair, but that's all i could do.

Comment: you are welcome....:) Btw, There's another option too.. if you want you can use that to get the result in any desired format. Tell me if you may want to know.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
SELECT ProductName, Price, FORMAT(Now(),'dd/MM/yyyy') AS PerDate
FROM Products;
```

Comment: `FORMAT` doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008 (check tags on question)

Answer (score 0):

`SET DATEFORMAT` allows you to **INSERT/UPDATE** dates with different formats without doing any special data conversions.It's not used to get  specific date format. The default input format of **us english** is **mdy**.If you need to get date in **dmy** format then you can change the language to **Birtish english** because the default date format is **dmy**

```
SET LANGUAGE 'british english'
```

Note:Changing database will effect on whole server not on individual databases